# Logic error in Java code to add hours and minutes

Tags: java

Can someone help me find the error in my logic? I have the following two java files (Main and Time):

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Dave
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //Array of Class Names
        String[] classList = new String[29];

        //create a file and scanner from class list
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Dave\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TutorData\\src\\classes.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

        int index = 0;
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            classList[index] = s;
            index++;
        }

        //for(String s : classList) System.out.println(s);

        //Parallel of Array of Total Times
        //set each time to 0 hours and 0 minutes
        Time t = new Time(0,0);
        Time[] total = new Time[29];
        for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++){
            total[i] = t;
        }

        File data = new File("C:\\Users\\Dave\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TutorData\\src\\TutorData.csv");
        scan = new Scanner(data);

        index = 0;
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print(s + " ");
            String[] tokens = s.split(",");
            System.out.print(tokens[3]+ " " + tokens[5]+" ");
            //split time token into hours and minutes
            String[] timeToken = tokens[3].split(":");
            Time timeToAdd = new Time(Integer.parseInt(timeToken[0]),Integer.parseInt(timeToken[1]));
            System.out.print(" " + timeToAdd.toString() + " ");
            //get class token
            String classToken = tokens[5];

            //get time so far for class and add timeToAdd
            switch (classToken) {
                case "ITIS 1212":
                    total[0] = total[0].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[0].toString());
                    break;
                case "ITIS 1213":
                    total[1] = total[1].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[1]);
                    break;
                case "ITIS 2110":
                    total[2] = total[2].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[2]);
                    break;
                case "ITIS 2300":
                    total[3] = total[3].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[3]);
                    break;
                case "ITIS 3110":
                    total[4] = total[4].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[4]);
                    break;
                case "ITIS 3130":
                    total[5] = total[5].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[5]);
                    break;
                case "ITIS 3200":
                    total[6] = total[6].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[6]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 1212":
                    total[7] = total[7].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[7]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 1213":
                    total[8] = total[8].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[8]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 2175":
                    total[9] = total[9].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[9]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 2214":
                    total[10] = total[10].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[10]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 2215":
                    total[11] = total[11].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[11]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 3146":
                    total [12] = total[12].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[12]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 3152":
                    total[13] = total[13].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[13]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 3155":
                    total[14] = total[14].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[14]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 3160":
                    total[15] = total[15].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[15]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 3166":
                    total[16] = total[16].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[16]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 3181":
                    total[17] = total[17].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " + total[17]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 4102":
                    total [18] = total[18].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " + total[18]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 4120":
                    total[19] = total[19].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[19]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 4166":
                    total[20] = total[20].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[20]);
                    break;
                case "ITCS 4180":
                    total[21] = total[21].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[21]);
                    break;
                case "MATH 1120":
                    total[22] = total[22].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[22]);
                    break;
                case "MATH 1241":
                    total[23] = total[23].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[23]);
                    break;
                case "MATH 1242":
                    total[24] = total[24].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[24]);
                    break;
                case "MATH 2164":
                    total[25] = total[25].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[25]);
                    break;
                case "STAT 1220":
                    total[26] = total[26].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[26]);
                    break;
                case "STAT 2122":
                    total[27] = total[27].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[27]);
                    break;
                case "STAT 2223":
                    total[28] = total[28].add(timeToAdd);
                    System.out.println("new Total time: " +total[28]);
                    break;
            }
            timeToAdd = new Time(0,0);
            index++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
            System.out.println(classList[i] + " " + total[i].toString());
        }

        scan.close();


    }

}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Dave
 */
public class Time {

    private int hour;
    private int min;

    public Time(int hour, int min) {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(int hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }


    public Time add(Time t) {
        this.min += t.min;
        if (this.min > 59) {
            this.hour += this.min/60;
            this.min = this.min%60;
        }
        this.hour += t.hour;

        return this;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return hour + ":" + min;
    }



}
```

And the following two data files:

```
8/26/2013,3:30 PM,3:45 PM,0:15,MJ,ITIS 2110,,,IT Infrastructure I,
8/27/2013,2:00 PM,4:00 PM,2:00,DF,ITCS 4120,,,Intro to Graphics,
8/28/2013,9:00 AM,10:30 AM,1:30,DF,ITCS 3146,,,Modern Operating Systems,
8/28/2013,10:30 AM,12:00 PM,1:30,DF,ITCS 2214,,,Data Structures,
8/28/2013,2:00 PM,3:35 PM,1:35,"AP",ITCS 2214,,,"Induction, Algorithm Complexities",
```

```
ITIS 1212
ITIS 1213
ITIS 2110
ITIS 2300
ITIS 3110
ITIS 3130
ITIS 3200
ITCS 1212
ITCS 1213
ITCS 2175
ITCS 2214
ITCS 2215
ITCS 3146
ITCS 3152
ITCS 3155
ITCS 3160
ITCS 3166
ITCS 3181
ITCS 4102
ITCS 4120
ITCS 4166
ITCS 4180
MATH 1120
MATH 1241
MATH 1242
MATH 2164
STAT 1220
STAT 2122
STAT 2223
```

However the output is a list of the classes and the total times which are all the same. Can anyone find the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be here

```
Time t = new Time(0,0);
Time[] total = new Time[29];
for(int i = 0; i < 29; i++){
    total[i] = t;
}
```

Every place within the array points to the SAME (not only equal) Time Object so you just have ONE single instance of the class Time. If you change the line to

```
total[i] = new Time(0,0);
```

than you have 29 different instances of class Time.

**EDIT:**

Additionally, the line `timeToAdd = new Time(0,0);` seems to be useless, because it's located at the end of the while block and at the beginning of the next iteration the pointer is set to a new object - there's no use to set the values back to 0.

Comment: Good eyes and nice catch. 1+

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an answer to your question, which is why I've made it a "Community Wiki", but Niklas already has the correct answer well in hand. Instead this is to give other unrelated suggestions that can't be a comment since it requires code. Your code has a **lot** of unnecessary redundancy and some dangerous code, and I suggest:

- Use a sorted Map `SortedMap<String, Time>` such as a `TreeMap` to associated your Times with the Strings.
- Then you can simply fill this map in a for loop and get rid of > 70% of the code in your program, making it easier to read and debug.
- Always close Scanner after using it. You create two Scanners but only close one. Best actually to do this automatically by using try with resources.
- When using Scanner, try to call `hasNextXxx()` in parallel with `nextXxx()`. So if you call `nextLine()` check for `hasNextLine()` as this increases code safety.

For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    private static final String FILE_1 = "src/pkg/MainF2.txt";
    private static final String FILE_2 = "src/pkg/MainF1.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SortedMap<String, Time> timeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        File file = new File(FILE_1);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            timeMap.put(s, new Time(0, 0));
        }
        scan.close();

        File data = new File(FILE_2);
        scan = new Scanner(data);

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print(s + " ");
            String[] tokens = s.split(",");
            System.out.print(tokens[3] + " " + tokens[5] + " ");
            String[] timeToken = tokens[3].split(":");
            Time timeToAdd = new Time(Integer.parseInt(timeToken[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(timeToken[1]));
            System.out.print(" " + timeToAdd.toString() + " ");
            String classToken = tokens[5];
            System.out.println();

            Time time = timeMap.get(classToken);
            time.add(timeToAdd);
        }
        for (String key : timeMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", key, timeMap.get(key));
        }
        scan.close();

    }

}
```